# Why does ItemLoader create a list from a single element

Tags: python, scrapy

I think my question is caused by some misunderstanding of some `scrapy` concepts. So I would be thankful if some could explain this to me.

Let us imagine I have the following spider:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from reddit.items import RedditItem
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst


class RedditspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "redditspider"
    allowed_domains = ["wwww.reddit.com"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/comments/5t8v7i/community_feedback_update_widow_mines_carriers/?st=iz7ba37h&sh=b7e9bd35']

    def parse(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=RedditItem(), response=response)

        comments = response.xpath(
            '//div[contains(@class,"usertext-body may-blank-within md-container ")]/div')
        comments = comments[1:]
        for comment_it in comments:
            comment = comment_it.extract()
            l.add_value('comment', comment)
            yield l.load_item()
```

Where `RedditItem` is defined in the following way:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from w3lib.html import remove_tags
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst


def _remove_tags(input):
    return input


class RedditItem(Item):
    comment = Field(input_processor=_remove_tags, output_processor=TakeFirst())
```

So everything is simple and straightforward. Now, to my question. In the first code sample `l` loader has a field `comments`. As far as I understand, when I do `l.add_value('comment', comment)`, input processors for this field are triggered. *Is that correct?*

As far as I get it, it is correct. In `l.add_value('comment', comment)` `comment` is a string, not a list. However, when I set a breakpoint in `_remove_tags` I see that `input` is actually a list of length 1. *So my main question is why does it happen?* Why do I pass a string and see a list there?

I looked into scrapy source code and found this is `_add_value`(line 90): `value = arg_to_iter(value)`. That makes things pretty clear,and it seems to be the reason why I see a list of length 1 there.

What is the design reasoning behind this line? Is this because in `scrapy` I can populate same field in item from different xpath/css requests? If so, that sort of makes sense to me. Then the question is: how do I go around this? Do I just apply `map(_remove_tags, input)` in input processor? Would this be a recommended solution here or I'm getting something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: have you confirmed that `comment = comment_it.extract()` is a string?

Comment: @eLRuLL yes. Set a breakpoint near add_value type(comment) ---> Out[2]: unicode. Seems to be  unicode string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, scrapy loaders are designed to handle multiple insertions in the same field, which you can test with:

```
from scrapy.loader.processors import Identity

class RedditItem(Item):
    comment = Field(input_processor=Identity(), output_processor=Identity())

l = ItemLoader(item=RedditItem(), response=response)
l.add_value('comment', 'first comment')
l.add_value('comment', 'second comment')

print l.output_value('comment') # ['first comment', 'second comment']
```

Now, because of that, you can check [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy-itemloader/blob/master/scrapy_itemloader/contrib/scrapylib/__init__.py#L87) what is the recommended processors for input and output (inside `default_output_processor` and `default_input_processor`) that scrapy programmers use.

As you can see they have a processor called `MapCompose` which takes every entry of the current value and applies every method defined as parameters.

Comment: Therefore, a nice way around would be to perform map(_remove_tags, input) in input_processor and then use TakeFirst as output processor? Am I getting this correctly?

Comment: `MapCompose(_remove_tags)`

Comment: @sof_dff Yes, you can see an [example](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html?highlight=remove_tags#declaring-input-and-output-processors) that does just that in the docs, mind the underscore though.